# Где разместить логику перед выводом шаблона страницы (Drupal 8)?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal8

Заходим в тему `default-theme > templates > page.html.twig`, вижу структуру `twig` с некоторым количеством простых условий по типу `if page.highlighted`.

А если нужно более сложную логику организовать, например между загрузкой страницы и выводом информации из этой страницы через шаблон `page.html.twig` разместить контроллер, который сделает некоторые манипуляции и после этого уже запустит этот шаблон.

Как в данном случае поступают в Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика получения данных должна быть в сервисах.

[Writing your first Drupal service](https://lakshminp.com/writing-your-first-drupal-service)

Symfony и Drupal 8 не являются традиционными реализациями архитектуры MVC, так как нет отдельного слоя модели, например  как в CodeIgniter.

Одной из наиболее важных функций Symfony и Drupal являются сервисы, которые есть (или должны быть) независимыми и многоразовыми реализациями различных функций.

Поэтому, если вам нужна логика выборки данных, вы можете создать свой собственный сервис, который делает это, и использовать эту службу в своем контроллере, вместо того, чтобы загрязнять его лишней логикой.

Еще отдельно в Drupal есть огромное количество хуков, посмотрите например на

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // your code
}
```

по нему можно понять общий принцип.

Можно помещать логику в эти хуки, но мне больше нравяться тонкие хуки и логику все таки переносить в сервисы. А в хуках просто использовать их.